# Where to subscribe to Redis event in ASP NET if I want to use DI to react to published event

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, publish-subscribe, stackexchange.redis

I use SignalR backplane with Redis. Its my first microservice.

The second microservice must subscribe to channel used to publish SignalR messages. But the problem is about where should I subscribe (in ASP NET app) to this event, if I want to use Dependency Injection (because I want to save published messages to database)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`IHostedService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) is the way to go - you can inject, what you wants here and set `IHostedService` for infinite run.